# BURG Installation errors

Tags: 11.10, grub2, dual-boot, burg

Yesterday, when I booted my computer I got the Grub loading screen, then my BIOS in an infinite loop. I was able to use boot repair to fix this and boot into both OSes.

Today I decided to install Burg again, but this time I installed *Super Boot Manager* and attempted to install that way. I was able to do so but there ware many pages of duplicate Ubuntu icons, making it useless. The entries are still there, how can I delete them? I used SBM to remove Burg and restore Grub. Grub  is working right now.

But, when I attempt to install Burg again, with or without SBM, I get the following errors:

```
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
    burg : Depends: burg-pc (= 1.98+20100623-1) but 1.98+20100623-2.3 is to be installed
    Depends: burg-themes but it is not going to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I'm using 11.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by running Computer Janitor in Ubuntu Tweak.